# Django DRF get ForeignKey values in serializer

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to retrieve all `Benchmarks` related to a `Node` in my serializer, but i'm not too sure how to retrieve them. Would I need to do some sort of reverse foreignkey lookup? Maybe my models are not made correctly?

```
class Node(models.Model):
    node_id = models.CharField(max_length=42, unique=True)
    wallet = models.CharField(max_length=42, null=True, blank=True)
    earnings_total = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    data = models.JSONField(null=True)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Benchmarks(models.Model):
    benchmark_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    benchmarked_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Node
        fields = ['earnings_total', 'node_id', 'data',
                  'online', 'version', 'updated_at', 'created_at', ]
```

Comment: Do you have a serializer for the `Benchmark` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a serializer for the `Benchmarks` model:

```
class BenchmarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Benchmarks
        fields = ['benchmark_score', 'benchmarked_at']
```

then we can use that serializer in the `NodeSerializer`:

```
class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    benchmarks_set = BenchmarkSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Node
        fields = ['earnings_total', 'node_id', 'data',
                  'online', 'version', 'updated_at', 'created_at', 'benchmarks_set']
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Benchmark` instead of <s>`Benchmarks`</s>.

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying your code.

```AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `benchmark_set` on serializer `NodeSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Node` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Node' object has no attribute 'benchmark_set'.```

Comment: @Phillip The reason is that your model has the name `benchmarks` and not `benchmark`. Therefore you must use `benchmarks_set`. The second thing is, a Serializer is not a model-object. You cannot invoke a model-based paremter at a serializer. For instance, `nodeserializer.benchmarks_set` wont work. However, `Node.objects.get(pk=1).benchmarks_set` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use HyperlinkedModelSerializer like this:

```
class BenchmarkSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        
    class Meta:
        model = Benchmarks
        fields = ['benchmark_score', 'benchmarked_at']

class NodeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    benchmark_set = BenchmarkSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Node
        fields = ['node_id', 'wallet', 'earnings_total', 'data', 'online',  
                  'version', 'updated_at', 'created_at', 'benchmark_set']
```